# Laravel Undefined variable: todos (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/content/apps/todo/app-todo.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently trying to display todos in my app-todo view, but I keep getting the error mentioned in the title.

In my controller I have:

```
public function index()
{
    $todos = Todo::all();
    return view('content.apps.todo.app-todo', ['todos' => $todos]);
}
```

and in my app-todo:

```
<div class="todo-task-list-wrapper list-group">
    <ul class="todo-task-list media-list" id="todo-task-list">
      @foreach($todos as $todo)
      <li class="todo-item">
        <div class="todo-title-wrapper">
          <div class="todo-title-area">
            <i data-feather="more-vertical" class="drag-icon"></i>
            <div class="title-wrapper">
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="customCheck1" />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="customCheck1"></label>
              </div>
                <span class="todo-title">Drink more water</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="todo-item-action">
            <div class="badge-wrapper me-1">
              <span class="badge rounded-pill badge-light-primary">Team</span>
            </div>
            <small class="text-nowrap text-muted me-1">Aug 08</small>
            <div class="avatar">
              <img
                src="{{asset('images/portrait/small/avatar-s-4.jpg')}}"
                alt="user-avatar"
                height="32"
                width="32"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      @endforeach
```

I have tried changing the code in the controller to `return view('content.apps.todo.app-todo')->with(['todos' => $todos]);` and using `compact('todos');` ,but I get the same error.

Update:
The model is the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Todo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['todoTitleAdd','task_assigned','task_due-date','task_tag', 'task_desc'];
}
```

and the web.php route:

```
Route::resource('todos', TodoController::class);
```

Comment: Please add Todo.php Model and routes/web.php to clarify the question.

Comment: @PooyaSabramooz I have added the missing code.

Comment: Please add `protected $table = 'todos';` if your table name is not todos.

Comment: @PooyaSabramooz I have added it to the Model, but it still gives me the error. My table in the database is named "todos".

Comment: Make sure that `Todo::all()` is imported from the correct place. 
for testing add `dd($todos)` below the `Todo::all()` line.

Comment: You may import it on the controller with `use App\Models\Todo;` line.

Comment: @PooyaSabramooz I think I have found the error, the application redirects to /app/todo instead of /todos , that is why I don't get the data. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index(){
$todos = Todo::all();
return view('content.apps.todo.app-todo',compact('todos'));
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).